# Tab into column headers with GridViewHeaderPresenter

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I'm using GridViewRowPresenter/GridViewHeaderRowPresenter and I'd like to allow the user to tab into the column headers. I've tried the following with no luck...

```
<GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="true" />
    </Style>
</GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
     <Style>
         <Setter Property="GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.Focusable" Value="true" />
     </Style>
  </GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
```